# Incremental training of random forest model using python sklearn

Tags: python, pickle, random-forest, training-data

I am using the below code to save a random forest model. I am using cPickle to save the trained model. As I see new data, can I train the model incrementally. 
Currently, the train set has about 2 years data. Is there a way to train on another 2 years and (kind of) append it to the existing saved model.

```
rf =  RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
print ("Trying to fit the Random Forest model --> ")
if os.path.exists('rf.pkl'):
    print ("Trained model already pickled -- >")
    with open('rf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        rf = cPickle.load(f)
else:
    df_x_train = x_train[col_feature]
    rf.fit(df_x_train,y_train)
    print ("Training for the model done ")
    with open('rf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        cPickle.dump(rf, f)
df_x_test = x_test[col_feature]
pred = rf.predict(df_x_test)
```

EDIT 1: I don't have the compute capacity to train the model on 4 years of data all at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're talking about, updating a model with additional data incrementally, is discussed in the sklearn [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#strategies-to-scale-computationally-bigger-data):

> Although not all algorithms can learn incrementally (i.e. without
>   seeing all the instances at once), all estimators implementing the
>   partial_fit API are candidates. Actually, the ability to learn
>   incrementally from a mini-batch of instances (sometimes called “online
>   learning”) is key to out-of-core learning as it guarantees that at any
>   given time there will be only a small amount of instances in the main
>   memory.

They include a list of classifiers and regressors implementing `partial_fit()`, but RandomForest is not among them. You can also confirm RFRegressor does not implement partial fit [on the documentation page for RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).

Some possible ways forward:

- Use a regressor which does implement `partial_fit()`, such as SGDRegressor
- Check your RandomForest model's `feature_importances_` attribute, then retrain your model on 3 or 4 years of data after dropping unimportant features
- Train your model on only the most recent two years of data, if you can only use two years
- Train your model on a random subset drawn from all four years of data.
- Change the `tree_depth` parameter to constrain how complicated your model can get. This saves computation time and so may allow you to use all your data. It can also prevent overfitting. Use Cross-Validation to select the best tree-depth hyperparameter for your problem
- Set your RF model's param `n_jobs=-1` if you haven't already,to use multiple cores/processors on your machine.
- Use a faster ensemble-tree-based algorithm, such as xgboost
- Run your model-fitting code on a large machine in the cloud, such as AWS or dominodatalab

Comment: Would SGD be a good alternative to random forest ? I am not sure how the new model would perform. SGD has a partial_fit API, so I can use it for  Online learning

Comment: Have you tried training an SGD classifier and comparing the performance to the RF model's performance? That's the only way to answer that question

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to find the important features and see if I can fit all 4 years into available RAM.

Comment: The parameter warm_start allows adding new estimators to the model based on the new coming data. This can be used for incremental learning.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the 'warm_start' parameter to True in the model. This will ensure the retention of learning with previous learn using fit call.

Same model learning incrementally two times (train_X[:1], train_X[1:2]) after setting ' warm_start '

```
forest_model = RandomForestRegressor(warm_start=True)
forest_model.fit(train_X[:1],train_y[:1])
pred_y = forest_model.predict(val_X[:1])
mae = mean_absolute_error(pred_y,val_y[:1])
print("mae      :",mae)
print('pred_y :',pred_y)
forest_model.fit(train_X[1:2],train_y[1:2])
pred_y = forest_model.predict(val_X[1:2])
mae = mean_absolute_error(pred_y,val_y[1:2])
print("mae      :",mae)
print('pred_y :',pred_y)
```

mae      : 1290000.0
pred_y : [ 1630000.]
mae      : 925000.0
pred_y : [ 1630000.]

Model only with the last learnt values ( train_X[1:2] )

```
forest_model = RandomForestRegressor()
forest_model.fit(train_X[1:2],train_y[1:2])
pred_y = forest_model.predict(val_X[1:2])
mae = mean_absolute_error(pred_y,val_y[1:2])
print("mae      :",mae)
print('pred_y :',pred_y)
```

mae      : 515000.0
pred_y : [ 1220000.]

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html

Comment: warm_state, just add more estimators. That means using only the new data, it will train a new estimator. And later decision is collectively made i.e. based upon the old+new estimators result. It wont trained a existing model, just merely add new estimators.

Comment: I tried this method, but I got `ValurError : Class label 21 not present`. How to resolve such type of issue.